# How can I do a 3D lookup table of a table with different sizes?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm trying to do a 3D lookup table in a simulink model, but I've got a problem with the sizes.

I've got 3 2D tables with different sizes:

```
Kbw1 604x6 double
Kbw2 490x5 double
Kbw3 664x7 double
```

I tried setting Kbw as:

```
Kbw(:,:,1)=Kbw1
Kbw(:,:,2)=Kbw2
Kbw(:,:,3)=Kbw3
```

But the dimmensions don't match.

Do you know any way to make this input suitable to the 3D lookup table block?

Thank you

Comment: I would suggest that you first interpolate all 3 of your layers on a common grid. You can use griddata() or interp2() for this. Once this is done, you can use your code to create that 3d Lookup table and use it with interp3()

Comment: If you post it as an answer I accept it, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you first interpolate all 3 of your layers on a common grid. You can use griddata() or interp2() for this. Once this is done, you can use your code to create that 3d Lookup table and use it with interp3().

Best,
Nras.